# R Shiny SweetAlert - Display alert depending on user input

Tags: r, shiny, sweetalert

I would like to send a SweetAlert to the app user depending on correct password input and file upload.

My app asks a user to upload a password protected Excel file using the `fileInput` widget and accepts a password using the `passwordInput` widget:

```r
  # file select
  output$file_select <- renderUI({
    fileInput("file_select","Import File:",buttonLabel = "Select",
              multiple = FALSE, accept = ".xlsx",placeholder = "No file selected")
  })
  # password input
  output$pword_input <-renderUI({
    passwordInput("pword_input","Password:", "", placeholder = "Enter Excel password")
  })
```

Reading of the Excel sheet is handled by `excel.link` and creates a reactive object called `raw.data()`:

```r
  raw.data <- reactive({
    # Read Excel file
    data_file <- input$file_select
    df <- xl.read.file(data_file$datapath,
                       password =  input$pword_input)
   return(df)
})
```

Documentation for `sendSweetAlert` only seems to provide examples for sending an alert on action button press. However, I would like the `observeEvent` to look for correct password input.

I cannot store the password within the app and so I have currently set the `observeEvent` that triggers the SweetAlert to look for the creation of the reactive object `raw.data()` as an indicator that the correct password has been input:

```r
  observeEvent(raw.data(), {
    sendSweetAlert(
      session = session,
      title = "Password Accepted",
      type = "success"
    )
  })
```

This functions, to a certain extent. If the correct password is input then the SweetAlert is displayed once the reactive object is created as desired. However, input of incorrect password crashes the app.

I hoped someone could help with the correct way to set this up please. I imagine my error is in the use of the observeEvent? However, without storing the password, i'm not sure how else to achieve my aim.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`xl.read.file` throws an error if the password is not correct. So you can try something like that (not tested):

```r
raw.data <- reactive({
    # Read Excel file
    data_file <- input$file_select
    df <- try(xl.read.file(data_file$datapath,
                           password = input$pword_input))
   return(df)
})

observeEvent(raw.data(), {
  if(inherits(raw.data(), "try-error")) {
    sendSweetAlert(
      session = session,
      title = "Wrong password",
      type = "error"
    )
  } else {
    sendSweetAlert(
      session = session,
      title = "Password Accepted",
      type = "success"
    )
  }
})
```

Comment: @ Stéphane Laurent Thank you for the reply. However, incorrect password still crashes the app. Console shows the password error. When not using SeetAlert, the error is displayed on screen in place of dependent content and the app does not crash...

Comment: @r0bt It crashes or it only displays the error in the console?

Comment: @ Stéphane Laurent With the code you suggested, the app crashes and displays the password error message in console along with a 'wrong number of dimensions' error triggered by the creation of a df that uses the excel sheet. When the sweet alert chunk is removed, wrong password does not crash the app